# What is the best way to call an api multiple times simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to call an API simultaneously, for e.g. user will enter how many clients to be simulated i.e. say 10. Then i want to simulate 10 api calls at the same time.

whats the best way to do that?

Comment: A very broad question. However it's common to use Parallel.ForEach or something else from the TPL for this kind of thing.

Comment: Basically I have a function which calls an api, I want to execute the function how many times user wants. I don't want to run one by one, instead should be able to run parallely. I tried Parallel.For but the action should be of type int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

```
void Main()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();   

    Console.WriteLine("For really parallel, operation should take about 1 second");

    Console.WriteLine("ReallyParallel");    
    sw.Start(); 
    ReallyParallel();
    sw.Stop();  
    Console.WriteLine($"ReallyParallel for {sw.Elapsed}");

    Console.WriteLine("NotReallyParallel_TPL");
    sw.Restart();   
    NotReallyParallel_TPL();    
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"NotReallyParallel_TPL for {sw.Elapsed}");

    Console.WriteLine("NotReallyButGoodOne");
    sw.Restart();   
    NotReallyButGoodOne();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"NotReallyButGoodOne for {sw.Elapsed}");
}
```

Use this is you want to raise a lot of calls

```
void NotReallyButGoodOne()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CallAPI()));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

TPL

```
void NotReallyParallel_TPL()
{
    Parallel.For(1, 10, i => CallAPI());
}
```

Use this if you want to raise a several calls (this is really parallel, but it can be very unefficient)

```
void ReallyParallel()
{
    var threads = new List<Thread>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() => CallAPI());
        t.Start();
        threads.Add(t);
    }

    foreach (var t in threads)
    {
        t.Join();
    }
}
```

your method

```
void CallAPI()
{
    // callig stuff
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

Comment: This will be solution for parallel, But how about simultaneous , if i take time, it will be different.

Comment: added timings, you can check it

Comment: Out of interest, why do you categorise `Parallel.For` as "Not Really Parallel"?

Comment: @stuartd because it depends of parallelism settings. By default is decides itself, when to run separate actions, and if you try to start 100 actions simultaneously, only several will run in parallel, others will wait until previous finished.

Comment: which method will be efficient, if user enters 1000 , in that case 1000 threads to be created or 1000 tasks

Comment: 1000 tasks will be better, but keep in mind that it will not be 1000 simultaneus requests.